# Cakephp why update not working?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

My controller code is

```
if(!empty($this->request->data['Color']['color_name']))
          {
              $color_name = $this->request->data['Color']['color_name'];
              $id = $this->request->data['Color']['id'];
              $this->Color->query("UPDATE colors set color_name='$color_name' WHERE id='$id'");
              $this->Session->setFlash('Color\'s Updated Successfully.', 'default', array('class' => 'oMsg1 oMsgError1'));
              $this->redirect('add_color');
          }
```

It works perfectly and updated record but when i put the value something like "student's",it can not be inserted student's.The error message is given below:

"Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's' WHERE id='4'' at line 1"

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Don't build SQL like that. Not only will you get syntax errors, you'll also get hacked through SQL injection.

Comment: Why aren't you using CakePHP's functions? `query()` is only for situations where you absolutely can't use anything else.

Comment: thanks for your advice Wooble  andjuhana

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly recommend using the [saving features cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) has for queries, in answer to your question, you need to escape the ' in "student's". For example

```
UPDATE colors set color_name='student''s' WHERE id='$id'
```

Comment: student's is assigned to a variable like $test.i.e
$test = "student's"

In that case what should i do?

Comment: Use [mysqli_real_escape_string($test)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). I must ask: why aren't you using cake's functions for saving?

Comment: when you stored in one variable you can use variable like this '".$test."'